# Strictly convex at

Tags: terminology, convex-analysis

Another terminology question:

If a function $f(x)$ is strictly convex **at** $y$, does this mean, for an already convex function:

a) $f'(y) = 0$, or equally, $y = \arg \min_y f(y)$

b) $f''(x) \geq 0$ and $f''(y) \neq 0$

c) Something else (specify)

Thanks, L

EDIT: Where $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x$, read $f'(x)$ as the subgradient of $f$ at $x$. i.e. $f'(x)=0$ means that for subgradient [a,b], $a \leq 0$, $b \geq 0$. Similarly for $f''$.

Comment: What is the derivative/subgradient of a subgradient?

Comment: How about: there is a line $l(x) = ax+b$ such that $l(y)=f(y)$ and $l(x)<f(x)$ for all $x\ne y$.  Do not mention derivatives!

Comment: @GEdgar: there's however the following problem (see my answer below). A function is convex if the set of subdifferentials is non-empty. You propose that $f$ is strictly convex at $y$ if there is an element in its subdifferentials that is strictly less than $f$ (except at $y$). But one can alternatively propose that the requisite property is that all subdifferentials be strictly less than $f$ except at $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Strict convexity is usually a global property; i.e., a function $f$ is (globally) strictly convex if any of the following hold for any $x\neq y$ in the domain of $f$:

1. For any $\alpha\in (0,1)$, $f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) < \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) f(y)$;
2. The subdifferential set $\partial f(x)$ (the set of sugradients at $x$) is nonempty, and $f(y) > f(x) + \langle g, y-x\rangle$, where $g\in \partial f(x)$ is arbitrary;
3. $\partial f(x)$ and $\partial f(y)$ are nonempty, and for any $g_x\in \partial f(x)$ and $g_y \in \partial f(y)$, $\langle g_x - g_y,x-y\rangle > 0$.

Usually you want strict convexity at least on a neighborhood of a point.  But if you insist on having strict convexity at a single point, you can adjust the above definition to say "$f$ is strictly convex at $x$ if for every $y$..."

You can find more on the above definitions in 
Hiriart-Urruty & Lemaréchal's beautiful book "Fundamentals of Convex Analysis", where in particular the above equivalence appears as Proposition D.6.1.3.

Comment: "Usually you want strict convexity at least on a neighborhood of a point, But if you insist on having strict convexity at a single point" - I don't!! This is exactly why I thought it was a bit of an odd thing to say.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that option (a) is non-ideal. Option (b) is also not good, since we would like the function $f(x) = x^4$ to be globally strictly convex. Using definition (b) this would fail at the origin. (BTW, your condition (b) and its suitable weakening to non-differentiable functions is more related to the notion of [strong convexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions), which is more restrictive than strict convexity.) (You should also consider the analogous problem that it is possible to have a strictly increasing function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is continuously differentiable with $g'(0) = 0$.)

Here I propose a slightly different notion.

In the general case, recall that the notion of convexity on a vector space can be summed up by: $\forall t \in [0,1]$, 
$$(1)\qquad\qquad f(t\vec{v} + (1-t)\vec{w}) \leq tf(\vec{v}) + (1-t)f(\vec{w})$$ 
Evidently there are three points under consideration: $\vec{v}$, $\vec{w}$, and $t\vec{v} + (1-t)\vec{w}$; in effect by the symmetry in the relation, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ can be considered together as the *end-point* case, while the other the *mid-point* case.

Let us see what happens in each of the cases.

Suppose we were to define "strictly convex at a point $\vec{y}$" to mean that the convexity relation (1) is a strict inequality for $\vec{v} = \vec{y}$ and all $\vec{w}$. That is

> **Definition** We say that the convex function $f$ over a vector space is strictly convex at an end-point $y$ if $\forall t\in(0,1)$ and $\forall \vec{w}\neq\vec{y}$, we have the strict inequality $$ f(t\vec{y} + (1-t)\vec{w}) < tf(\vec{y}) + (1-t)f(\vec{w}) $$

Similarly we define

> **Definition** we say that the convex function $f$ over a vector space is strictly convex at a mid-point $y$ if $\forall t\in(0,1)$ and $\forall \vec{v},\vec{w}\neq \vec{y}$ such that $\vec{y} = t\vec{v} + (1-t)\vec{w}$, the strict inequality holds $$ f(\vec{y}) < tf(\vec{v}) + (1-t)f(\vec{w}) $$

The two definitions are not equivalent!

*Example* Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x) = |x|$. Then $f$ is strictly convex at the mid-point 0, but no-where is $f$ strictly convex at an end-point.

On the other hand, it is possible to have 0 be the only point at which $f$ has a strictly convex end-point.

*Example* Define $f$ the following way: let $f(\pm 2^{k}) = 4^k$ for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and let $f$ be linear between $2^k$ and $2^{k+1}$ (similarly between $-2^k$ and $-2^{k+1}$; in the following we'll only do things on the positive half line, since the argument can be reflected to the negative half-line with minimum modification). And set $f(0) = 0$. This $f$ is continuous. It is clearly convex, and it is clearly not strictly convex at any point other than 0, since for any point $x > 0$, $f$ is linear on the segment $2^{k} \leq x < 2^{k+1}$. But from the definition it is clear that

- if $x > 2^{k}$, then $f(x) > \frac{x}{2^k} f(2^k)$
- if $x < 2^{k}$, then $f(x) < \frac{x}{2^k} f(2^k)$

which implies that for all $0<t<1$, $f(tx) < tf(x)$. This implies that $f$ is strictly convex at the endpoint 0.

Now, we have the implication that if a convex function $f$ is strictly convex for the endpoint $\vec{y}$, it must also be strictly convex for the midpoint $\vec{y}$.

*Proof* Let $\vec{v},\vec{w},t$ such that $\vec{y} = t\vec{v} + (1-t)\vec{w}$. Let $s\in (0,1)$, and let $\vec{v}' = s\vec{y} + (1-s)\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}' = s\vec{y} + (1-s)\vec{w}$. which implies that $\vec{y} = t\vec{v}' +(1-t)\vec{w}'$. By convexity, 
$$ f(\vec{y}) \leq tf(\vec{v}') + (1-t)f(\vec{w}') $$
by strict convexity of the end point
$$ f(\vec{v}') < sf(\vec{y}) + (1-s) f(\vec{v}) $$
so 
$$ f(\vec{y}) < sf(\vec{y}) +  t(1-s) f(\vec{v}) + (1-t)(1-s)f(\vec{w}) $$
which implies that $f$ is strictly convex at the midpoint $y$. q.e.d.

So depending on whether you want a corner point like what was given in the first example to be a point at which the function is strictly convex, you may choose one definition or the other.

---

To connect to the notion of partial derivatives: if $f$ is convex, it is (locally) Lipschitz continuous, and hence admits directional derivatives $D_{\vec{r}}f$, which is a non-decreasing function along the line $\vec{x} + s\vec{r}$ for any fixed $\vec{x}$. The notion of *strictly convex at an endpoint $\vec{y}$* is equivalent to saying that for any $\vec{r}$ and any $s > 0$, the derivative

$$ D_{\vec{r}} f(\vec{y} + s\vec{r}) > D_{\vec{r}}f(\vec{y}) $$

and where the *strictly convex at a midpoint $\vec{y}$ is equivalent (I think; this last part I'm a bit iffy on) to saying that for any $\vec{r}$, and any $s,t > 0$,

$$ D_{\vec{r}} f(\vec{y} + s\vec{r}) > - D_{-\vec{r}} f(\vec{y} - t\vec{r}) $$

The implication of "endpoint strict convex" $\implies$ "midpoint strict convex" then is a consequence of the fact that for convex functions, $D_{\vec{r}}f \geq - D_{-\vec{r}} f$. (If $f$ is differentiable, then the equality is guaranteed.)

---

To connect to the notion of subgradients: Define the set of subgradients $\partial f(y)$ to be the set of linear functions $l(x)$ satisfying

- $l(y)  = f(y)$
- $l(x) \leq f(x)$

A function being convex means that the set of subgradients $\partial f(y)$ is nonempty for any $y$.

Let $l\in \partial f(y)$. We say that $l$ is a "strict subgradient" if $l(x) < f(x)$ for every $x \neq y$. Then the two definitions above are equivalent to:

- $f$ is strictly convex at the endpoint $y$ iff $\forall l\in\partial f(y)$, $l$ is strict.
- $f$ is strictly convex at the midpoint $y$ iff $\exists l\in\partial f(y)$ such that $l$ is strict. (See also GEdgar's comment above.)