# Existence of subgradient for strictly convex function on the domain

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, subgradient

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ be proper, lower semicontinuous and convex, and $\operatorname{dom}f=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid f(x)<\infty\}$ be the domain of $f$. Assume further that $f$ is strictly convex on $\operatorname{dom}f$. Then  is the subgradient $\partial f(x)$ nonempty for all $x\in \operatorname{dom}f$?

The accepted answer in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57021/strictly-convex-at) seems to suggest the assertion is correct. But the reference there assumes $\operatorname{dom}f=\mathbb{R}^n$. Could you refer me to a proof of the statement?

Comment: Is this a counterexample https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2293011/42969 ?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for pointing out this counterexample.